# CKEDITOR: can I create a widget that uses a different plugin

Tags: ckeditor

I have a plugin that inserts a chunk of HTML in the form of a div with various attributes but not other content. I have a 'doubleclick' handler that opens my plugin dialog and populates it when the user doubleclicks. It would be nice if my inserted DIV was a "widget" so I could drag it around and select it. I see in the widget docs how to create a widget, but does that mean I have to recreate my entire plugin in the widget framework? Can I just somehow turn it into a widget "as is?"

Comment: To further clarify: how do I make an arbitrary container be a widget? E.g., can I make things inside <b> tags be a widget?

Answer (score 1):

I added this code to the `init` section of my plugin:

`editor.widgets.add( 'anyName', {
        upcast: function( element ) {
        //indicate the thing you want to be a widget: 
        //e.g., <div class=subbox>:
        return element.name == 'div' && element.hasClass( 'subbox' );
        }
    });`

And this seems to work. Did I do it right? Any unforeseen consequences here?